# How many tables are needed to implement the scenario depicted in my entity-relationship diagram?

Tags: database-design, erd

How many *tables* are required to implement the scenario expressed in the ERD shown below?

[image]

My try:

- `Table (CR2)` with the columns `{B1, C1, C2}`
- `Table (R1)` with the columns `{A1, P, B1}`
- `Table (A)` with the columns `{A1, A2, A3}`
- `Table (R3)` with the columns `{A1, B1, Q}`
- `Table (B)` with the columns `{B1, B2}`

Have I got it right? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is mostly correct, except Q is a dependent attribute of R3, not a table on its own.

Comment: Why is C not a table of its own?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ C is a weak entity set, R2 is an identifying relationship. C must be implemented as `(B1, C1, C2)` where `(B1, C1)` identifies the weak entity set. The relationship `(B1, (B1, C1))` is derivable from that, it would be redundant to represent it as a separate table.